# Delphi2009 IDE using 100% CPU to save files

Tags: delphi

These days i found my Delphi 2009 IDE something wrong on saving files (using 'Save All' button), it just peak my CPU to 100% for around 10 seconds

Can anyone help to explain why this happening? I just curious what causes the save action to peak CPU

---

Finally, i got the answer!
it's because Delphi's project file, which's with extension "dproj", include thousands of Misc_Files, causing Delphi IDE peak CPU when saving files

Thank you, guys.

Comment: Does it happen immediately after a clean boot of your system?

Comment: yep. Actually, it happen all the time when i running the project, and it really faze me for a developer like me who always wanna save files on every piece of changes

Comment: Check the size of your dfm-files, maybe you accidentally included a 50mb bitmap or something like that. I've seen it happen.

Comment: Which process is using 100% CPU?

Comment: To Jeroen, BDS.exe using 100% CPU.

Comment: To Ville, it's believe that the new version of my project hasn't include such a BMP or something like that

Comment: @Leo you can use the @ sign to notify specific users you reply to them; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: @Leo can you try Process Explorer and see which thread in bds.exe is using 100% CPU? You can get Process Explorer her: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: @Jeroen: Thanks for your suggestion, i'm new to the StackOverflow, and i'll try the Process Explorer

Comment: @Leo you are most welcome; also try the Process Monitor thing in the answer by @netcodecz

Answer (score 3):

Did you install a virus checker? It could be scanning files as you are writing them.

Comment: Sorry that i should provide more information for you. Actually, there are two version of my projects, one's old version while the other one is an update one. I found that the old version is working fine, but the new one will peak CPU while clicking 'Save All', and they're all running in the same workstation

Comment: So, what is the difference between them ? I've ported a lot of projects from the older Delphi versions to D2009, but this never happened to me.

Comment: I also believe so before came across this. The new version of my project just bug fix some items and introduce new forms for enhancement. But i haven't included any big bmp, or other resource files, it's just strange happening this to me

Answer (score 1):

For this type of problem I use Process Monitor (known before as Filemon) from ex-sysinternals
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

This program show time log of saving.
Usually this show me file with problem (readonly or so on).

In one case problem was one option in CnPack. Do you use any anti-virus program?

Comment: i don't think the anti-virus will affect the final result, since if i run two of my project, one new version and the old, only the new one came across this issue